# MediaSource.addSourceBuffer fails with video/ogg and video/webm

Tags: html, firefox, video, media-source

I've gotten some MediaSource code working on my XP/FF50 machine that creates a MediaSource and adds a SourceBuffer.
On the XP machine, both of these codecs work:

```
'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'
'video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'
```

When I bring the code over to my Win10/FF50 machine, both of these codecs throw these similar errors:

```
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: video/ogg; codecs="theora vorbis"
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: video/webm; codecs="vp8 vorbis"
```

My ogg and a webm files play correctly on the Win10 machine when setting the video's ***src*** attribute.

I've checked the following:

```
console.log(MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4')); <--returns true
console.log(MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/ogg')); <--returns false
console.log(MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/webm')); <--returns false
var videoElement = document.createElement('video');
console.log(videoElement.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"')); <--returns probably
console.log(videoElement.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"')) <--returns probably
console.log(videoElement.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"')) <--returns probably
```

Any idea what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox's `about:config`, change `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` to `true`.